# Access NodeJS server installed on Linux server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, linux, server

I created my App from this boilerplate
https://github.com/Bikranshu/express-react-boilerplate

Now I uploaded it to a live Linux server and Node server is running.
[Screenshot of running server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mlxK.png)

But I am unable to access it through Browser with IP address of server.
http://ip_address:3000
After waiting long in browser it is showing timeout error.
Please guide me how can I access the node/react app from browser.

Comment: Can you please post a link to the live app?

Comment: I am sorry, server owner didn't allow me to share the link. Please note there is no output and nothing in console logs.

Comment: ask the host, it sounds like *shared* means there is simply a reverse proxy or pre routing nat in front and your expected to setup a domain and point it to it, or setup your local `hosts` file, unless its a vps of sorts your unlikely to have a direct ip access to it.

Answer (score 2):

`Server running at <ipaddress>` is a local IP, are you in a different network than the server? If so, you should be typing `https://<public ipaddress>:3000`

**UPDATE**

Hosting services usually only forward port 80 (http) or 443 (https.) This means that your port 3000 is not allowed for public access. To fix your problem you need to change the listening port.

Check line 42 on
`server/app.js` change `'port'` to `"80"` or check `package.json` and edit `npm start` to set port to 80

Comment: It is shared ip address of server https://www.screencast.com/t/dhLPQVk3rtz

Comment: is there a firewall that might be blocking ports other than 80 on that hosting

Comment: I have SSH and cPanel access. Please guide me how to check it?